# How many nodes can be a black node with one red child?

Tags: data-structures, red-black-tree

consider a red-black tree with n internal nodes,where n is even. At most how many of them can be a black node with one red child?

A. n/2
B. n
C. [lg(n+1]-1
D. [lg(n+1]
E. none of the other choices

---

In the red-black tree with 26 nodes that reaches the solution of the problem above, what is the maximum height of the tree? A tree with one node is assumed to have height 1.

A. 5
B. 6
C. 7
D. 8
E. 9

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is A, but only because it asks "at most", rather than a more categorical "how many can be red".

There are trees with an even internal node count where it simply isn't possible to have each black node have a single red child. An example of this is where N is four. It is, however, possible where N is 2 or 8.

Where N is 2, the following tree works:
1B
2R

While for N=8:

```
      6B
3R      7B
```

2B  4B     8R
1R      5R

Basically, it can be made to work on any tree where the most extreme internal nodes (that is, the node furthest from the root on any given path) are all black and any other black nodes have a single red child by adding a red child to those most-extreme nodes.

By this I mean turn the following 5-node tree into the 8-node tree from above:
6B
3R      7B
2B  4B